# EclipseLink class and xml mix mappings

Tags: eclipselink

I wanted to mix class based JPA configuration with using annotations together with xml based configuration and it works fine in terms of Dynamic Fields Extensions - I can add to xml fields that are not defined in class and they are being used fine.
The question is how to do that with mappings - I wanted to add OneToOne or OneToMany mapping to the xml and have that working but no luck at the moment. Is that even possible to add for existing class new mapping to new class, in xml orm file?

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/solutions/extensible001.htm which describes various ways to make entities dynamic and completely change the orm.xml and have it be reloaded (calling refreshMetadata).

Comment: Extensible entities work fine - I wanted to add relation/join in xml file - and this is an issue here.

Comment: So what happens when you add the new entity/relationship to the eclipselink-orm.xml and call refreshMetadata ?  Just saying no luck doesn't describe what issue you are getting, and as the doc states, it is expected to work.